# Remove Unused Resource feature of Android Studio delete content of String's item that is being in used

Tags: android, kotlin

It's a normal task to remove all unused resources include String's items. But today I've found a weird thing, after choosing ***"Refactor -> Remove Unused Resource ...",*** this feature **does remove content of some String's items that is in being used!** 

Somehow it only remove String's content that inside HTML tags like `<font></font>`. It's pretty strict when I removed some text content of my co-worker by this reason.
 
 [image]

Anyone know how to prevent this? Hope we have some solutions to make this feature become reliable enough.

Comment: Smells like the tool is using a regex to modify xml, and regex is not powerful enough for actually parsing xml. No idea what to do to fix it other than remove those by yourself.

Comment: You can probably report this to google.

Comment: @laalto oh my experience is very careful with Strings.xml file and some cases of getting drawable dynamically (**resources.getIdentifier()**) when use this feature

Comment: @HartWoom oh that sounds make sense

Comment: resource string can't have "recognized" xml tag inside.
The refactor tool regex will see `font` tag as a different (unused) resource. Have you tried escaping the font tag?

Comment: Something like: `<string name="about_text">ABC&lt;font size="18"&gt;your text...&lt;/font&gt;</string>`